# Find pandoc executable from R

Tags: r, rstudio, pandoc

`rmarkdown::find_pandoc` helps us to find the `pandoc` executable w/o the need of specifiying any environmental variable when running form within RStudio:

```r
## in Rstudio
!is.null(rmarkdown::find_pandoc()$dir)
# [1] TRUE
```

However, when running the same command from a plain R console I get:

```r
### R console
!is.null(rmarkdown::find_pandoc()$dir)
# [1] FALSE
```

Reading the documentation pf `?rmarkdown::find_pandoc()`, explains why I am getting these results:

> ```
> dir: A character vector of potential directory paths under which
>           ‘pandoc’ may be found. If not provided, this function
>           searches for ‘pandoc’ from the environment variable
>           RSTUDIO_PANDOC (the RStudio IDE will set this variable to the
>           directory of Pandoc bundled with the IDE), the environment
>           variable PATH, and the directory ‘~/opt/pandoc/’.
> ```

I want now to write a script which can be run from the command line (specifically **not** from within `RStudio`), which needs `pandoc` to be found. As per the help I could set my `PATH` to assure that `pandoc` is also found from the command line, but as soon as I want a colleague of mine to use the script, I have to make sure that his/her `PATH` is set accordingly and I want to avoid that.

However, I do know that everybody has `Rstudio` installed (not at the same location though), so if I knew the location of `RStudio` I could derive `pandoc's` location too.

Is there any reliable way to get the path of `Rstudio` from the console (i.e. also when `Rstudio` is **not** running)?

To make a long story short: how can I find `Rstudio` even if it is not running`?

Comment: did you find an answer to this? - i have the exact same problem

Answer (score 1):

This could work, it is based on linux, but I guess if you are in other system, it could be adapted:

```
pandoc_path <- system2("find", args="/usr/lib/rstudio -name pandoc -type f", stdout = T)

path_sep <- ":"

Sys.setenv(PATH = paste0(Sys.getenv("PATH"),path_sep, sub(".pandoc$","",pandoc_path )))
```